# Detect Bootcamp from .net application

Tags: c#, .net, bootcamp

I'm currently working on an application for Windows written in WPF (C#) and I want to have some features enabled only when the application is running on an Apple computer which is running Windows via Bootcamp. I didn't find any questions about it anywhere nor solutions for it online. Is it possible to detect Bootcamp? If so, how?

Comment: You could attempt to detect the bios vendor using WMI and if that mentions Apple it is a Bootcamp installation (or parallels - haven't checked this theory). As far as I know if it's running in bootcamp it may as well be any intel PC

Comment: Also look for registry keys or devices that are Apple-specific, and look for Parallels ones to rule out a VM.  But yes, Boot Camp is dual booting, it is booting Windows native like any other PC not as a guest of something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never thought of checking BIOS Vendor information. Thanks to Kell for the idea. Here is a solution for others:

**First of all, you need to add `System.Management` as a reference.** You'll also need to add these namespaces:

```
using System.Management;
using Windows.System;
```

After this, you'll need the following code to understand if the machine is made by Apple or not:

```
public bool IsMadeByApple()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
    ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

    string manufacturer = "";
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
    {
        manufacturer = (string)obj["Manufacturer"]; // Will be "Apple Inc." if it's an Apple computer
    }
    return (manufacturer == "Apple Inc.");
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(IsMadeByApple().ToString());
```

This will pop up a message box. It will say "True" if it's an Apple computer, if not then it will say "False".

> This solution is only tested on an Early 2015 MacBook Pro running Bootcamp. This solution may not work on different models, but it will likely work.